# jQuery get add row to table on window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a clipboard box where I can copy some columns from a table on the parent page/window to a pop up window.

Parent window elements:

1. Table with checkbox per row (selection)
2. Button to copy rows to another window table

Popup window elements:

1. Table which has no row (tbody only)

**FILE 1: JavaScript file of Parent Window**

```
         $("#button_copy").on("click", function() {
            var l_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>clipboard/";
            var l_name = "ClipboardWindow";
            var l_height = 500;
            var l_width = 1000;

            var l_params = 'status=1' +
                           ',resizable=1' +
                           ',scrollbars=1' +
                           ',width=' + l_width +
                           ',height=' + l_height +
                           ',left=0' +
                           ',top=0';

            // get selected rows details
            var table_result = $("#table_result");
            var row_contents = [];
            $('input:checkbox:checked', table_result).map(function() {
                var row = [];
                row['item_code'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.row_item_code').text();
                row['sales_description'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.row_sales_description').text();
                row['buy_description'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.row_buy_description').text();
                row['sell'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.row_sell').text();
                row['buy'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.row_buy').text();

                row_contents.push(row);
            });
            // display selected rows on the pop up window
            var row_html = "";
            row_contents.forEach(function(row) {
                row_html = row_html + "<td>" + row['item_code'] + "</td>";
                row_html = row_html + "<td>" + row['sales_description'] + "</td>";
                row_html = row_html + "<td>" + row['buy_description'] + "</td>";
                row_html = row_html + "<td>" + row['sell'] + "</td>";
                row_html = row_html + "<td>" + row['buy'] + "</td>";
            });

            if ((myWindow == null) || (myWindow.closed)) {
                console.log("new window");
                // open pop up window and get document for processing
                myWindow = window.open(l_url, l_name, l_params);
                myWindow.document.getElementById("tbody_result").append("<tr>" + row_html + "</tr>");
            } else {
                console.log("existing window");
                myWindow.document.getElementById("tbody_result").append("<tr>" + row_html + "</tr>");
            }
        });
```

**FILE 2: HTML File of Popup Window:**

```
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="table_clipboard">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Item Code</th>
                                    <th>Sales Description</th>
                                    <th>Buy Description</th>
                                    <th>Sell</th>
                                    <th>Buy</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="tbody_result">
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!-- /.table-responsive -->
                    </div>
```

I am not able to make it work.. Here are my problems:

1. The row is not created upon window.open
2. It has error initial: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null` which maybe the dom has not yet been loaded since call?
3. The JS appends new row but only after the page was loaded by previous button click (which is okay)
4. The JS appends only add 1 row and 1 column which is not in HTML format but text (image attached below)

[image: Image of the resulting row]

Comment: Why don't you use a modal dialog instead, why popup window?

Comment: @skobaljic it might need another page so the parent window can be closed or change the contents of the parent page table from search. This new window will contain all items they need to copy for faster process.

Comment: Each row you append should be wrapped in `<tr>`, not **all** html inside one table row.

Comment: There is no `append` function on a HTMLElement. You're probably looking for `appendChild`, but that doesn't take HTML text. I think you want to do `$('#tbody_result', myWindow.document)` instead.

Comment: @skobaljic I think I included it in the append `append("<tr>" + row_html + "</tr>");` I will modify this one.. Thank you

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thank you! That actually fixed the problem of adding rows! +1.. But still the rows are not added upon page load of the pop up window.

Comment: append is a jquery function use appendChild() instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my question as I found some work around to the other problems I enumerated in the Question, and since no one has posted an answer yet.

**Problems 1 & 2 solved**: Instead of the following code:

```
       if ((myWindow == null) || (myWindow.closed)) {
            console.log("new window");
            // open pop up window and get document for processing
            myWindow = window.open(l_url, l_name, l_params);
            myWindow.document.getElementById("tbody_result").append("<tr>" + row_html + "</tr>");
        }
```

I use the following to check if DOM is loaded on:

```
           if ((myWindow == null) || (myWindow.closed)) {
                // open pop up window and get document for processing
                myWindow = window.open(l_url, l_name, l_params);
                $(myWindow).on('load', function() {
                    $('#tbody_result', myWindow.document).append(row_html);
                });
            }
```

**Problems 3 & 4 solved**: @MikeMcCaughan - suggested that instead of this one:

```
myWindow.document.getElementById("tbody_result").append("<tr>" + row_html + "</tr>");
```

I should use:

```
$('#tbody_result', myWindow.document)
```

and it worked. Since I'm working in jQuery, this is a better solution that is using selector.